# Can my Zelle payment be reversed?

Tags: fraud

I was contacted by a fraudulent person and I sent them 3 payments under false pretenses. They walked me through the process and instead of receiving money, I sent it. My bank basically stated that I'm out the money. Is there any way these transactions can be reversed?  PLEASE HELP!

Comment: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/109076/how-can-i-get-a-refund-from-a-seller-who-only-accepts-zelle is similar

Comment: @RonJohn I have seen videos of scammers convincing the victim to give them remote desktop access and then modify the HTML inside the browser session e.g. to change a button that says "send" to one that says "receive" to trick the victim into going ahead with multi factor authorisation. Don't understimate the sneaky techniques that scammers will use to trick people.

Comment: @JBentley: Hmmm that might be enough to cause Zelle's service agreement to fail to exist due to lack of agreement.

Comment: @Joshua: No, because *I'm sure*, without even looking, that their service agreement contains a clause which says something like "you agree to never let anyone else access your account." When you let someone remote desktop into your browser, you violate that clause.

Comment: @Kevin: How about if somebody else accessed remote desktop and signed the user up for Zelle in the first place.

Comment: @Joshua: That just makes the violation happen earlier in the process.

Comment: I'm not convinced this is a duplicate. This question is closer to "Someone hacked into my bank account and sent themselves a Zelle payment", than "I accidentally bought something from a scammer and paid via Zelle." The question ought to be if a bank *can* reverse a Zelle payment rather than whether they are willing to per some terms of service agreement.

Answer (score 8):

Zelle [has a form](https://www.zellepay.com/support/scam) for reporting scammers.

It may not help to get your money back, though, as Zelle states on the form: "We will report the information you provide to the recipient’s bank or credit union to help prevent anyone else from having the same experience."